# probability of sum of a given set of whole numbers being greater than a certain number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations

There are total of n balls in k boxes. Box one contains n1 balls, box 2 contains n2 balls and so on. The probability of picking balls from boxes is p1,p2,...,pk. We can pick either all the balls in a box or none. How can we find the probability that sum of balls picked from the boxes will be greater than or equal to ceil(n/2) . I want to know the general procedure for approaching such questions, answer would be nice but I want to generalize this question and find the probability of numbers being greater than some number. I think there will be some recursive relation like finding the sum of heads or tails in unfair coins but I am not able to think of such a relation.

EDIT: Think of it as balls kept in n bags.We move sequentially from bag 1 to n. We pick certain number of bags from them. We have to find the probability that sum of balls obtained from the chosen bags is greater than ceil(n/2).

Comment: This sounds interesting but I don't quite understand. When you say "We can pick either all the balls in a box or none", do you mean that literally? I.e., you can pick $0$ balls from the first box or all $n_1$ balls, but not some number $x_1$ such that $0 < x_1 < n_1$? Also, does the probability change as you choose balls (a.k.a. choosing with/without replacement)? And, how many balls are you picking altogether?

Comment: We have to move sequentially from one box to the other(lets say in ascending order from 1 to n) and when we reach the box we have to make choice either to choose balls from box or not to to chose balls. We are choosing without replacement. see edit for further explanation.

Comment: Problem sounds exactly like the one in an ongoing contest : http://www.codechef.com/AUG13/problems/SHIRO 
And looking at your other questions, I am very sure its from the contest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward method is probably just to recursively marginalize the distribution, each time reducing the number of boxes and (in one branch) reducing the sum threshold. That is, $P(sum_{1..i}>n_{thresh}) = P(sum_{1..i}>n_{thresh} | picked_i)p_i + P(sum_{1..i}>n_{thresh}|\neg picked_i)(1-p_i) = P(sum_{1..i-1}>(n_{thresh}-n_i))p_i + P(sum_{1..i-1}>n_{thresh})(1-p_i)$. Obviously, at a certain point you're looking at thresholds less than zero or greater than all the remaining boxes, which are your termination cases.

This takes exponential time in the general case, but the problem is NP-complete so that's not really negotiable.

Comment: Can we use DP to reduce the complexity

Comment: Possibly, though offhand I can't see a simple DP algorithm. You could also reorder the bins from largest to smallest, to prune branches as quickly as possible.

Comment: What if we fix the path( not necessarily moving from bins with largest to smallest).